# Moving a mutable trait object reference into a box

Tags: rust

How do I move a mutable trait object reference into a box? e.g. I'd perhaps expect

```rust
struct A {a:i32}
trait B {
    fn dummy(&self) {}
}
impl B for A {}

fn accept_b(x:&mut B) -> Box<B> {
    Box::new(*x)
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = A{a:0};
    accept_b(&a);
}
```

<sub><sup>[(playpen link)](http://is.gd/VDnoUa)</sup></sub>

... to work, but instead it errors out as

```
<anon>:8:5: 8:13 error: the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `B` [E0277]
<anon>:8     Box::new(*x)
             ^~~~~~~~
<anon>:8:5: 8:13 note: `B` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
<anon>:8     Box::new(*x)
             ^~~~~~~~
<anon>:8:14: 8:16 error: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
<anon>:8     Box::new(*x)
                      ^~
<anon>:7:33: 9:2 note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 7:32...
<anon>:7 fn accept_b(x:&mut B) -> Box<B> {
<anon>:8     Box::new(*x)
<anon>:9 }
<anon>:8:14: 8:16 note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected `B`, found `B`)
<anon>:8     Box::new(*x)
                      ^~
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
<anon>:8:5: 8:17 note: ...so that it can be closed over into an object
<anon>:8     Box::new(*x)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~
<anon>:13:14: 13:16 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&mut B`,
    found `&A`
(values differ in mutability) [E0308]
<anon>:13     accept_b(&a);
                       ^~
error: aborting due to 3 previous errors
```

... effectively whining that I can't move the trait object into the box. Do I *have* to put the value in a box *first*, and then cast that box into a box-of-a-trait later?

Shouldn't the mutability rules transitively ensure that the trait I get in `accept_b` is the sole owner of the underlying object and thereby support movement into a box? Or does Rust not record the necessary information to provide that nicety? Am I misunderstanding move vs mutable borrow semantics? What's going on?

Comment: Okay, I currently think that the reason is an extension of why you can't move out of mutable borrows in a context where you don't know where you're borrowing from: because it's expected that some later statement *may* mutably borrow one stack frame up. This then propagates to traits, but in a slightly more convoluted way that, if true, isn't particularly clear in the error messages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shouldn't the mutability rules transitively ensure that the trait I get in `accept_b` is the sole owner of the underlying object and thereby support movement into a box?

No, absolutely not. `accept_b` is borrowing the reference, not owning it.

The mutability rule only makes you certain that you are the only one borrowing the object, but it does not give you ownership.

It is actually never possible to move out of borrowed content and leaving the reference dandling. If you want to move out of a `&mut` reference, you can use functions like `std::mem::replace(..)`, but they require you to put an other object in place of the one you are moving out, which in turns involve copying actual memory data, and thus the type must be `Sized`.

So no, it is not possible to move out of a `&mut T` if `T` is not `Sized`.